# Regex is working on Chrome but not in Safari

Tags: javascript, regex, safari

The following regex is working just fine on Chrome, but it breaks in Safari with the following error: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name`.

Regex: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_{|}~]+[@](?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?<!-)[.][a-zA-Z]{2,}$/`

I am new at Regex, so I have no idea why it seems to work on 1 browser but not the other, is there anyway I can fix this?

Example Data:

```
random#email@domain-good.com
random@domain-bad-.com
```

The 2 example should fail because it starts/ends with a `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern contains a lookbehind and Safari does not support lookbehinds yet. Actually, the `(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?<!-)` pattern means to match one or more alphanumeric or hyphen chars while forbidding `-` to appear at the start and end of this sequence. It is simple to refactor this pattern part to `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*`.

So, the regex will look like

```js
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/
```

`[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` matches one or more alphanumeric chars and then any zero or more sequences of a hyphen followed with one or more alphanumeric chars.

Note you may simply use `@` instead of `[@]` as `@` is never special in any regex, and `[.]` can be written as `\.`, which means a literal dot.